# Collaborating on Xcode 4.x project with Xcode 5

Tags: ios, xcode4, xcode5

Is it possible to collaborate on a Xcode 4.x project with Xcode 5, without any compatibility problems between the two versions?

Comment: Why use XCode 4.x still? You can install old iOS SDK versions as well as download old version simulators so there isn't any technical reason to use XCode 4.x.

Comment: There is, not everyone can upgrade to Xcode 5 as it requires OSX Mountain Lion and above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

> There were no changes done to project file so you can safely use it on
>   both versions same time. Xcode 5 might just prompt you for some
>   automatic settings changes - so you should ignore that otherwise Xcode
>   4 might be asking again to revert those changes.

Source: Grzegorz Krukowski